# Principal value for this question?

Tags: branch-cuts

I have this question in my notes:

[image]

Here is the answer:

[image]

How in the world do they get that starting equation for -i??

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

We have $z=|z|\cdot e^{i\cdot\arg(z)}$ for any complex number $z$ where $|z|$ is its distance from the origin when drawn on the complex plane, and $\arg(z)$ is its *argument*, i.e. the angle of the vector $z$ closed with the right wing of the real axis.

Now, we have $\ |-i|=1\ $ and $\ \arg(-i)=3\pi/2$.